# Need help with Scala

Tags: java, scala

Could anyone help me to understand this code? I don't know anything about Scala nor heard about it.

```
def maxSubseq(l: List[Int]) = l.scanRight(Nil : List[Int]) {
    case (el, acc) if acc.sum + el < 0 => Nil
    case (el, acc) => el :: acc
} max Ordering.by((_: List[Int]).sum)

def biggestMaxSubseq(l: List[Int]) = l.scanRight(Nil : List[Int]) {
    case (el, acc) if acc.sum + el < 0 => Nil
    case (el, acc) => el :: acc
} max Ordering.by((ss: List[Int]) => (ss.sum, ss.length))

def biggestMaxSubseq[N](l: List[N])(implicit n: Numeric[N]) = {
    import n._
    l.scanRight(Nil : List[N]) {
        case (el, acc) if acc.sum + el < zero => Nil
        case (el, acc) => el :: acc
    } max Ordering.by((ss: List[N]) => (ss.sum, ss.length))
}

def linearBiggestMaxSubseq[N](l: List[N])(implicit n: Numeric[N]) = {
    import n._
    l.scanRight((zero, Nil : List[N])) {
        case (el, (acc, _)) if acc + el < zero => (zero, Nil)
        case (el, (acc, ss)) => (acc + el, el :: ss)
    } max Ordering.by((t: (N, List[N])) => (t._1, t._2.length)) _2
}
```

Could this code be implemented in Java?

Comment: Buy a book start from [Beginning Scala - David Pollak](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Scala-David-Pollak/dp/1430219890)

Comment: Yes, I think it could be implemented in Java, but that's sort of silly.  A scala compiler will let you produce class files that you can use directly from java.

Comment: My brain hurts.  Forget about implementing this convoluted mess in Java, I think it needs to be implemented more cleanly in Scala!

Comment: Where did you encounter this code, and why do you need to understand it?  Is this homework, or something you'll be maintaining? In the first case nobody's going to just hand you the answer on a silver plate, in the second case, why is the original author not helping you out?  You must, at the very least, show you've made *some* sort of effort on your own, and don't want to just leech valuable time from others.

Comment: @Nishant - If you must recommend a book, the definite reference is [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), written in part by Martin Odersky, the creator of the language (and of the Java compiler).

Comment: @Kevin Wright -- I read it partially at the book shop. I found it's very thick. Plus, I am from Java, I find Beginning Scala easier to start with. I have Programming in Scala in my list of books-to-read in order to perfection Scala. But, to start with, I feel Pollak's book is good.

Comment: @Kevin I don't see any problem with this code, aside from the use of the known-to-be-broken-and-besides-inefficient `scanRight` method. Since everything gets ordered at the end, I don't see why the much superior `scanLeft` method isn't being used, unless this is a naive translation from Haskell, where `scanr`/`foldr` are more efficient than `scanl`/`foldl`.

Comment: @Kevin Also note that each method is a variation on the same theme. The first is `Int`-specific, and doesn't have a tie-breaker. The second break ties based on length of subsequence. The third is generic, and the fourth avoids using `.sum` inside the `foldRight` loop.

Comment: @Daniel the obvious first fix is to extract the duplicated code that finds the subsets, then reuse it in the other methods. Code such as `def maxSubseq(l: List[Int]) = subseq(l) max Ordering.by((_: List[Int]).sum)` would go a long way to making it self-documenting.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, it can be implemented in Java. It will require more effort, though. Let's see some points here.

```
def linearBiggestMaxSubseq[N](l: List[N])(implicit n: Numeric[N]) = {
```

This declares a method which receives a `List` of `N`, and an implicit parameter `Numeric[N]`. Implicit parameters are usually derived by the compiler itself by looking up certain places for declarations that match the required parameter -- almost like a dependency injection.

In this case, `Numeric[N]` is a class that provides basic mathematical operations, and for which there are instances for all numeric types provided in the standard library. The only things this method uses from `Numeric` are `plus` and `zero`.

Java doesn't have implicits, so the equivalent Java API would be a bit more cumbersome to use, requiring one to pass an additional parameter.

Also, I don't recall any equivalent to `Numeric` in Java. `java.lang.Number` doesn't provide methods such as those found in `BigInt` and `BigDecimal`. You'd have to write your own equivalent of `Numeric`, and then write instances to cover all numeric types, and then the client code would have to pass the instance explicitly. If there's an alternative in Java to going to all that effort, I'd love to hear about it.

```
    import n._
```

All this does is allow the code to do `acc + el` instead of `n.plus(acc, el)`, and `zero` instead of `n.zero`. How it does that is beyond the scope of this question.

```
l.scanRight((zero, Nil : List[N])) {
```

There's no `scanRight` equivalent in Java. You'd have to turn this into a `while` loop, but it isn't particularly hard to do. A `scanRight` will traverse the list from right to left (though I don't see any reason why the code does it right to left instead of the more easy and efficient left to right).

As it traverses the list (`l`), it will call a function passing two parameters: the current element, and an "accumulator". Here the accumulator is a `Pair`, a shallow object with a pair of getters and setters for two elements in contains. The first time around, this pair is initialized with `zero` and `Nil` (an empty list).

The method called by `scanRight` is supposed to return something of the same type as the accumulator -- so, being passed a `Pair[N, List[N]]`, it should return a new `Pair[N, List[N]]`.

Finally, `scanRight` will create a collection with the results of the method it is calling.

```
    case (el, (acc, _)) if acc + el < zero => (zero, Nil)
    case (el, (acc, ss)) => (acc + el, el :: ss)
```

Plenty of matter matching in this code, which will have to be replaced by a series of `if`/`else` statements. Verbose, but not particularly troublesome.

In this particular case, `(el, (acc, _))` and `(ec, (acc, ss))` are just the parameters being passed. They *could* embody tests, but, here, they don't. The only test being made is whether `acc + el < zero`. If so, it returns `(zero, Nil)`, if not it returns `(acc + el, el :: ss)`. As I said earlier, `Nil` is an empty list. Here, `el :: ss` returns a *new*  list with `el` prepended to the list `ss`.

```
} max Ordering.by((t: (N, List[N])) => (t._1, t._2.length)) _2
```

At least Java's numeric classes usually implement `Comparable`, even if they do not implement an interface providing numeric operations. There are many `Ordering.by` instances, each of which will require a `Comparator` equivalent or some other ad hoc solution.

At any rate, this will return the maximum element (`max`), using an `Ordering` (equivalent to `Comparator`) which considers first the value of the first element of the pair, and the *length*  of the second element of the pair (which is a list).

Finally, `_2` will discard the first element of the pair and return the second element.

This is the most complex of all methods. The previous ones are more simpler, at the cost of being less generic and efficient.

So, the Java version will be more verbose, for sure, but aside the `Numeric` issue, should be pretty straight-forward to write. Then again, the `Numeric` issue is pretty critical.